# How to ensure all samples from specific group are all togehter in train/test in sklearn cross_val_predict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, cross-validation, train-test-split

I have a dataframe, where each sample belong to a group. For example:

```
df = a b c group
     1 1 2  G1
     1 6 1  G1
     8 2 8  G3
     2 8 7  G2
     1 9 2  G2
     1 7 2  G3
     4 0 2  G4
     1 5 1  G4
     6 7 8  G5
     3 3 7  G6
     1 2 2  G6
     1 0 5  G7
```

I want to run `cross_val_predict`, while ensuring that all of the samples from the same group are in the test or all are in the train.
I want to split the data to 4 folds - but be sure that all the rows from the same group are together in the test or in the train.

So, for example, rows 0,1 and rows 4,5 will be in the train but rows 3, 6 (G3) will be in the test

Is this possible? I saw the `group` arg in the docs, but it is not very clear and I didn't find any examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold) as parameter for `cv` in [`cross_val_predict()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html):

```
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, groups, cv=GroupKFold())
```

Note that `groups` array represents groups in the data that we want to be in the same training/test set. It is NOT an array of class labels.

For example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupKFold, cross_val_score

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=15, random_state=0)

model = LogisticRegression()
groups = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, groups, cv=GroupKFold(n_splits=3))

print('cross val scores: {}'.format(scores))
```

Comment: What is groups here? Where do I feed it with the grouping column name ('group' in my case)

Comment: Please, see my answer.

Comment: thanks, I still don't understand what the groups arg represent? Notice there should be less folds than number of unique groups in my data, please see edit

Comment: Groups represent, as the name suggests, subsets in the data that you want to be in the same training/test set. In that example, the first, second, and third sample will be ALWAYS in the same fold (either the training or the test set).